Install Tensorflow on M1 Max Mac using Conda and VS Code
I'm having the hardest time getting Tensorflow to install on my Mac and I've tried several approaches.  Searching the internet for solutions led to recreating my Conda environments, trying pip, uninstalling things and trying again, downgrading Python, etc.  Now I'm hoping someone can recreate my problem or see what I hope to be something very stupid I'm doing that makes this not work on my machine.
First, here is the problem.
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

results in
{
    "name": "ModuleNotFoundError",
    "message": "No module named 'tensorflow.keras'",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 20
     17 from xgboost import XGBRegressor
     19 import tensorflow as tf
---> 20 from tensorflow.keras import layers, Sequential
     21 from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'"
}

In this current iteration of attempting to fix the problem, here are my settings.
(cpsproject) ben@BenBook final % which python
/Users/ben/opt/anaconda3/envs/cpsproject/bin/python
(cpsproject) ben@BenBook final % python --version
Python 3.11.10
(cpsproject) ben@BenBook final % conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/ben/opt/anaconda3/envs/cpsproject:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_py-xgboost-mutex         2.0                       cpu_0  
absl-py                   2.1.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
anyio                     4.6.2           py311hecd8cb5_0  
appnope                   0.1.2           py311hecd8cb5_1001  
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py311h6c40b1e_0  
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0  
async-lru                 2.0.4           py311hecd8cb5_0  
attrs                     24.2.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
babel                     2.11.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.12.3          py311hecd8cb5_0  
blas                      1.0                    openblas  
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
bottleneck                1.4.2           py311h9b7fc35_0  
brotli                    1.0.9                h6c40b1e_8  
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h6c40b1e_8  
brotli-python             1.0.9           py311hcec6c5f_8  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h6c40b1e_6  
c-ares                    1.19.1               h6c40b1e_0  
ca-certificates           2024.9.24            hecd8cb5_0  
certifi                   2024.8.30       py311hecd8cb5_0  
cffi                      1.17.1          py311h9205ec4_0  
charset-normalizer        3.3.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
comm                      0.2.1           py311hecd8cb5_0  
contourpy                 1.2.0           py311ha357a0b_0  
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
cyrus-sasl                2.1.28               h3973f50_1  
debugpy                   1.6.7           py311hcec6c5f_0  
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
flatbuffers               24.3.25              h6d0c2b6_0  
fonttools                 4.51.0          py311h6c40b1e_0  
freetype                  2.12.1               hd8bbffd_0  
gast                      0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
gettext                   0.21.0               h4e8c18a_2  
giflib                    5.2.2                h46256e1_0  
glib                      2.78.4               hcec6c5f_0  
glib-tools                2.78.4               hcec6c5f_0  
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
grpcio                    1.62.2          py311hab2016f_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.1               hcec6c5f_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.1               h6c40b1e_1  
h11                       0.14.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
h5py                      3.12.1          py311ha611a00_0  
hdf5                      1.12.1               ha01d115_3  
httpcore                  1.0.2           py311hecd8cb5_0  
httpx                     0.27.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
icu                       73.1                 hcec6c5f_0  
idna                      3.7             py311hecd8cb5_0  
ipykernel                 6.29.5          py311hecd8cb5_0  
ipython                   8.27.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
ipywidgets                8.1.2           py311hecd8cb5_0  
jedi                      0.19.1          py311hecd8cb5_0  
jinja2                    3.1.4           py311hecd8cb5_1  
joblib                    1.4.2           py311hecd8cb5_0  
jpeg                      9e                   h46256e1_3  
json5                     0.9.25          py311hecd8cb5_0  
jsonschema                4.23.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
jsonschema-specifications 2023.7.1        py311hecd8cb5_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0           py311hecd8cb5_9  
jupyter-lsp               2.2.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
jupyter_client            8.6.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
jupyter_console           6.6.3           py311hecd8cb5_0  
jupyter_core              5.7.2           py311hecd8cb5_0  
jupyter_events            0.10.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
jupyter_server            2.14.1          py311hecd8cb5_0  
jupyter_server_terminals  0.4.4           py311hecd8cb5_1  
jupyterlab                4.2.5           py311hecd8cb5_0  
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0  
jupyterlab_server         2.27.3          py311hecd8cb5_0  
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.10          py311hecd8cb5_0  
keras                     3.4.1           py311hecd8cb5_0  
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py311hcec6c5f_0  
krb5                      1.20.1               h428f121_1  
lcms2                     2.12                 hf1fd2bf_0  
lerc                      3.0                  he9d5cce_0  
libabseil                 20240116.2      cxx17_h548131f_0  
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h6c40b1e_8  
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h6c40b1e_8  
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h6c40b1e_8  
libclang                  14.0.6          default_hd95374b_1  
libclang13                14.0.6          default_habbcc1a_1  
libcurl                   8.9.1                h3a17b82_0  
libcxx                    14.0.6               h9765a3e_0  
libdeflate                1.17                 hb664fd8_1  
libedit                   3.1.20230828         h6c40b1e_0  
libev                     4.33                 h9ed2024_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                hecd8cb5_1  
libgfortran               5.0.0           11_3_0_hecd8cb5_28  
libgfortran5              11.3.0              h9dfd629_28  
libglib                   2.78.4               h19e1a8f_0  
libgrpc                   1.62.2               hf2926fd_0  
libiconv                  1.16                 h6c40b1e_3  
libllvm14                 14.0.6               h26321d7_4  
libnghttp2                1.57.0               h9beae6a_0  
libopenblas               0.3.21               h54e7dc3_0  
libpng                    1.6.39               h6c40b1e_0  
libpq                     17.0                 h184c1cd_0  
libprotobuf               4.25.3               h34eed0b_0  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h1de35cc_0  
libssh2                   1.11.0               hf20ceda_0  
libtiff                   4.5.1                hcec6c5f_0  
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h46256e1_1  
libxgboost                2.1.1                hab2016f_0  
libxml2                   2.13.1               h6070cd6_2  
llvm-openmp               14.0.6               h0dcd299_0  
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcec6c5f_1  
markdown                  3.4.1           py311hecd8cb5_0  
markdown-it-py            2.2.0           py311hecd8cb5_1  
markupsafe                2.1.3           py311h6c40b1e_0  
matplotlib                3.9.2           py311hecd8cb5_0  
matplotlib-base           3.9.2           py311hc25a08b_0  
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py311hecd8cb5_0  
mdurl                     0.1.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
mistune                   2.0.4           py311hecd8cb5_0  
ml_dtypes                 0.4.0           py311he327ffe_0  
mysql                     8.4.0                hbfece55_1  
namex                     0.0.7           py311hecd8cb5_0  
nbclient                  0.8.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
nbconvert                 7.16.4          py311hecd8cb5_0  
nbformat                  5.10.4          py311hecd8cb5_0  
ncurses                   6.4                  hcec6c5f_0  
nest-asyncio              1.6.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
notebook                  7.2.2           py311hecd8cb5_1  
notebook-shim             0.2.3           py311hecd8cb5_0  
numexpr                   2.10.1          py311hc59c7be_0  
numpy                     1.26.4          py311h91b6869_0  
numpy-base                1.26.4          py311hb3ec012_0  
openjpeg                  2.5.2                hbf2204d_0  
openldap                  2.6.4                h6e6fb41_0  
openssl                   3.0.15               h46256e1_0  
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
optree                    0.12.1          py311h1962661_0  
overrides                 7.4.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
packaging                 24.1            py311hecd8cb5_0  
pandas                    2.2.2           py311he327ffe_0  
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pcre2                     10.42                h9b97e30_1  
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3  
pillow                    11.0.0          py311h9c91434_0  
pip                       24.2            py311hecd8cb5_0  
platformdirs              3.10.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
ply                       3.11            py311hecd8cb5_0  
prometheus_client         0.21.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.43          py311hecd8cb5_0  
prompt_toolkit            3.0.43               hd3eb1b0_0  
protobuf                  4.25.3          py311h43dadc6_0  
psutil                    5.9.0           py311h6c40b1e_0  
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2  
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
py-xgboost                2.1.1           py311hecd8cb5_0  
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pygments                  2.15.1          py311hecd8cb5_1  
pyparsing                 3.2.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
pyqt                      5.15.10         py311hcec6c5f_0  
pyqt5-sip                 12.13.0         py311h6c40b1e_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1           py311hecd8cb5_0  
python                    3.11.10              h4d6d9e5_0  
python-dateutil           2.9.0post0      py311hecd8cb5_2  
python-fastjsonschema     2.20.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
python-flatbuffers        24.3.25         py311hecd8cb5_0  
python-json-logger        2.0.7           py311hecd8cb5_0  
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pytz                      2024.1          py311hecd8cb5_0  
pyyaml                    6.0.2           py311h46256e1_0  
pyzmq                     25.1.2          py311hcec6c5f_0  
qt-main                   5.15.2              hf83fbd5_11  
qtconsole                 5.6.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
qtpy                      2.4.1           py311hecd8cb5_0  
re2                       2022.04.01           he9d5cce_0  
readline                  8.2                  hca72f7f_0  
referencing               0.30.2          py311hecd8cb5_0  
requests                  2.32.3          py311hecd8cb5_1  
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4           py311hecd8cb5_0  
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1           py311hecd8cb5_0  
rich                      13.7.1          py311hecd8cb5_0  
rpds-py                   0.10.6          py311hf2ad997_0  
scikit-learn              1.5.1           py311he327ffe_0  
scipy                     1.14.1          py311hedc7b93_0  
seaborn                   0.13.2          py311hecd8cb5_0  
send2trash                1.8.2           py311hecd8cb5_0  
setuptools                75.1.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
sip                       6.7.12          py311hcec6c5f_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
snappy                    1.2.1                h6d0c2b6_0  
sniffio                   1.3.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
soupsieve                 2.5             py311hecd8cb5_0  
sqlite                    3.45.3               h6c40b1e_0  
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
tensorboard               2.17.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
tensorboard-data-server   0.7.0           py311hf1618be_1  
tensorflow                2.17.0          cpu_py311hb3d9b59_0  
tensorflow-base           2.17.0          cpu_py311h0426836_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.17.0          cpu_py311h7aa49ff_0  
termcolor                 2.1.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
terminado                 0.17.1          py311hecd8cb5_0  
threadpoolctl             3.5.0           py311h85bffb1_0  
tinycss2                  1.2.1           py311hecd8cb5_0  
tk                        8.6.14               h4d00af3_0  
tornado                   6.4.1           py311h46256e1_0  
traitlets                 5.14.3          py311hecd8cb5_0  
typing-extensions         4.11.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
typing_extensions         4.11.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
tzdata                    2024b                h04d1e81_0  
unicodedata2              15.1.0          py311h6c40b1e_0  
urllib3                   2.2.3           py311hecd8cb5_0  
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
webencodings              0.5.1           py311hecd8cb5_1  
websocket-client          1.8.0           py311hecd8cb5_0  
werkzeug                  3.0.6           py311hecd8cb5_0  
wheel                     0.44.0          py311hecd8cb5_0  
widgetsnbextension        4.0.10          py311hecd8cb5_0  
wrapt                     1.14.1          py311h6c40b1e_0  
xgboost                   2.1.1           py311hecd8cb5_0  
xz                        5.4.6                h6c40b1e_1  
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0  
zeromq                    4.3.5                hcec6c5f_0  
zlib                      1.2.13               h4b97444_1  
zstd                      1.5.6                h138b38a_0  

Any ideas?
I've tried both updating and downgrading tensorflow and keras.  Originally I was using Python 3.12.x, but I learned that was a no-no.  Downgrading Python to 3.11.10 didn't work either, but the tensorflow documentation suggests that it's compatible with 3.11.  The environment cpsproject is my third iteration of my virtual environment and it's the second iteration where I started by installing tensorflow first in hopes that any conflicts would be hashed out by Conda with subsequent package additions.  That didn't work either, and that's the latest state I'm at now.

do you have a tensorflow.py script file in your project directory?

I do not have a tensorflow.py script in my project directory.
